# How to tag FB event with Bundle in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have encountered a strange behavior to log facebook events with a specific Bundle.

Here is my code that works

```
fbLogger.logEvent("account_created");
```

If i see logs, i get

```
Result: Success
Events JSON: [
{
"_eventName": "account_created",
"_logTime": 1450255727,
"_ui": "UserCreateFbActivity_"
}
]
```

But if i try to send Bundle like this

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
if (userToPost.getSponsorCode() != null && !userToPost.getSponsorCode().isEmpty()) {
    extras.putBoolean("sponsor", true);
} else {
    extras.putBoolean("sponsor", false);
}

extras.putBoolean("facebook_connect", true);
fbLogger.logEvent("account_created", extras);
```

Logs are differents and event is not logged

```
Invalid app event name or parameter:
Result: Success
Events JSON: [
null
]
```

sdk version : 4.8.1

Comment: i dot get where you are calling `_eventName`

Comment: `_eventName` is the log from facebook sdk.

Comment: i got that, but how you are getting value from that ?

Comment: When i call `fbLogger.logEvent("account_created");`, i get these logs

Comment: i think you can't simply call a value from json like this

Comment: Yes, this logic is in the sdk but i don't understand why adding Bundle send a bad json

Comment: If you try non-boolean values does it work? also with the current implementation, are you seeing the events in the Insights page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is do not use boolean type ><. Thx to @ifaour

So here is my solution

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
if (userToPost.getSponsorCode() != null && !userToPost.getSponsorCode().isEmpty()) {
    extras.putString("sponsor", "true");
} else {
    extras.putString("sponsor", "false");
}
```

I don't understand why boolean type is not valid but this solution works ...